# Yii How to display the rendered query before it's executed

Tags: php, mysql, yii

In Yii How to display the rendered query before it's executed.

```
$sql="SELECT * from users WHERE user_id = :user_id";
    $command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
    // replace the placeholder ":user_id" with the actual username value
    $command->bindParam(":user_id",$user_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    echo "<br/>".$command->getText();
```

I would like to print query included with bind param
e.g user_id = 1 then

```
SELECT * from users WHERE user_id = 1
```

Comment: You won't be able to see the SQL with bound parameters.

Comment: do a var_dump($user_id) to see what it contains

Answer (score 2):

While it's not possible to see the prepared query with bind params until it's executed, it's certainly possible to check it in the log. You just have to enable so called 'general_query_log' of MySQL; there are several ways of doing this, most simple, I suppose, is to do...

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

... in MySQL shell. Then you can try your query; it will be logged as it is in `mysql.general_log`, so you can check it with something like...

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log;
```

Don't forget to disable logging when it's not needed anymore:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';
```

And here's [more info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html) about it.

Comment: Might be worth to mention that `mysql.general_log` might be set to a logfile, if anybody is wondering why nothing is written to the table.

Answer (score 1):

Yii works on top of PDO and assorted classes. And with [PDOStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php), and [`bindParam`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

> Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.

So you won't be able to see it before execution.